# What does the polar equation $r=k\theta$ represent? (Fibonacci Sequence, Golden Ratio, Archimedes' Spiral, or Torus)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Using the polar coordinate system, $r$ increases directly with $\theta$. In other words, $r=k\theta$. Which of the following shapes is constructed?

A) Fibonacci Sequence

B) Golden Ratio

C) Archimedes' Spiral

D) Torus

After a bit of research, I'm inconclusive about which shape is constructed. Anybody know what shape it is given the aforementioned information? Appreciate it guys

Comment: Ok, you draw a curve: is a curve a sequence of numbers ? Is a curve a number ? Is a curve a curve ? Is a curve a donut surface ? Is this a joke for Christmas or what ?

Comment: I had confused it with the golden spiral, which I interpreted to be the golden ratio by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A)
  The Fibonacci sequence is sequence of integers, not a geometrical curve.
- B) The golden ratio is an algebraic number $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$, not a geometrical curve.
- D) A torus is a three-dimensional geometrical object, not a curve.

Even without knowing the name of the curve $r=k\theta$, you could figure out that the answer is C.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I had seen a curve like representation of the golden ratio on google which puzzled me.

Answer (score 1):

A radius that varies as it rotates builds a... ? Obviously not a circle, since the radius of the latter is constant... but something round or circular nevertheless, right ? Now, of all your $4$ choices, which one comes closest to such a shape ? :-)

Comment: Yes but doesn't the golden ratio also represent something circular (sorta speak) too? That's what threw me off

Comment: I assume you are referring to the [golden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral) or [logarithmic spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral), correct ? In that case, know that its equation is NOT linear, as in the case of the [Archimedean spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral), but exponential: $r=ae^{b\theta}$, instead of $r=a+b\theta$, as is obviously the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you joking?

This couldn't be a serious question.

You should draw the shape constructed. Or you can at least think about how it may look like.

Does the line look like a sequence of numbers?

Does the line look like a number?

Does the line look like a line?

Does the line look like a 3 dimensional body or surface?

By answering these questions you'll get the final answer.

Comment: It's a practice test question, yes. Forgive me for posting but I thought the same way

Comment: This site is trying to advise anybody to search a bit before posting a question. If you just google the terms, you won't spend time by writing the question.

Comment: I did do that. I was confused by seeing the geometrical representation of the golden ratio (which looked like a curve to me). I had no idea to be honest I haven't seen this material in 10+ years.

Comment: Oh and just so you know, that's a question for a california subject matter exam. If you think that's ridiculous, I'm on the same boat as you.

Comment: @V-X: Try to [be nice](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (C).  First of all, if you really wanted to parse the question very precisely, the only two choices that are *shapes* are (c) and (d).  In addition, the $r = k \theta$ curve, by definition, produces an Archimedes Spiral.  If your radius increases by a factor of $\phi$ (Golden Ratio = 1.618) for every turn of $\theta = \pi / 2$, then you have the Golden Spiral.  This can be approximated using Fibonacci squares.  You can search multiple posts here in StackExchange for review of that (for example: [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342713/does-a-spiral-generated-using-fibonacci-squares-do-a-good-job-of-approximating-a)).

Comment: By the way, I don't understand the sarcasm of some of the other posts.  If you don't like the question, don't answer it!  Please understand that people are posting here because they may be genuinely confused.